# Proving/disproving an argument's validity

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

> Oleg is a math major or Oleg is an economics major. If Oleg is a math major, he is required to take Math 362. Therefore, Oleg is an economics major or is not required to take math 362.

I have to prove the validity/invalidty of the above argument, so I represented it with logical symbols as follows:

$$p \lor  q ,\\
p \to r ;\\
\therefore \quad q \lor  ~r$$

I built some cases from truth table:
When p, q and r are true, p->r is also true and the conclusion is true.
But when p and r are true and q is false, p V q is true, p -> r is true but q v ~r is false. This proves the invalidity of the argument? If not, what is wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are right, the argument is invalid.  I wonder if there is a misprint in the way that the problem was presented to you, or the way that you copied the problem.  If Oleg is not an Economics major, then he is a Math major, and so he must take Math 362.  So, either Oleg is an Economics major, or he must take Math 362.

Comment: I guess not, the purpose of the exercise was only to check for validity or invalidity of the argument, not to draw conclusions or infer things on it. Maybe this was intended?

Comment: Basically, since you are using a truth table, the argument is invalid iff you can find a row for which the argument's corresponding conditional is F. $\quad$ You found it in the row $(p,q,r)=(T,F,T).$

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't mention whether or not Oleg is required to take Math 362.  Not knowing that, we can't determine whether or not he is a math major.  Plus, or is inclusive by default (the first option, or the second option, or both), so he could be both a math major AND and an economics major.  Basically, not enough possibilities are considered to draw a definite conclusion so this is invalid.